# Do text alignment in a for each statement not compiling

Tags: swift, object, foreach, properties, text-alignment

In my swift code below it uses a forEach statement. The problem is some of the items in the the set can not do a text alightment. For example a text alignment is not possible in a uiimageview. So I tried to write a code of something that might possibly work but a compile error does occur. You can see what I tried to code in the comment block below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [player1Score,player2Score,clearBtn,player1UpBTN,player1DownBtn,player2UpBTN,player2DownBtn,play1Lbl, play2Lbl,play1text,play2text,resetBtn,resetBtn,GameLabel,GameText,gameIncrease,gameDecrease,submit].forEach{
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
            red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            alpha: 1
            

             //part of cocde I tried that does not work
            if $0 is = UITextField {
                $0.textalignment = .cent
            }
        )
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're missing a closing paren on your call to UIColor.

Next, your if statement. Since your array of objects are of different types, the array is going to be of type `Array<Any>`.
Your `if $0 is UITextField` means "only execute the body of this if statement if the current object being iterated is of type `UITextField`. The compiler won't then treat `$0` as being of that type however.

Instead of using `if $0 is <type>`, I would use `if let` optional binding to create a new local variable of type `UITextField`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    [player1Score,player2Score,clearBtn,player1UpBTN,player1DownBtn,player2UpBTN,player2DownBtn,play1Lbl, play2Lbl,play1text,play2text,resetBtn,resetBtn,GameLabel,GameText,gameIncrease,gameDecrease,submit].forEach{
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
            red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0.0...1),
            alpha: 1
        )
        if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
            // if the if let succeeds, `textField` will be 
            // a var of the correct type
            textfield.textalignment = .cent
        }
    }
```